# DialogFragment buttons are outside of background

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I create a dialog fragment, which has a positive and a negative button.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        binding = NewRecipeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(binding.root)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok) { _, _ ->
                if (isValid()) {
                    listener.onShoppingItemCreated(getRecipe())
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                        HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                            "<font color='red'>" +
                                    "<b>" +
                                    "<big>" +
                                    "Recipe must have a name!" +
                                    "</big>" +
                                    "</b>" +
                                    "</font>",
                            HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null)
            .create()
    }
```

I also have a background for my DialogFragment which i set here:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_recipe, container, false)
        if (dialog != null && dialog!!.window != null) {
            dialog!!.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        }
        return view;
    }
```

My problem is that the background gets applied to the dialog fragment's xml, but the positive, negative buttons are not located there therefor they are out of the DialogFragment's body

Dialog fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="94.5"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dip">


        <!--NAME-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!--INGREDIENTS-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
            android:text="@string/ingredients"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etIngredients"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <!--PREAPARATION-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
            android:text="@string/preparation"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPreparation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <!--HOWTOMAKE-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
            android:text="@string/howToMake"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etHowToMake"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <!--CATEGORY-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
            android:text="@string/category"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!--ESTIMATED COST-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
            android:text="@string/estimatedCost"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEstimatedPrice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Drawable/rounded button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="40dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/black" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/filterPressed" android:endColor="@color/filterPressed"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="40dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/black" />
            <solid android:color="@color/filterBasic"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="40dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/black" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/filterBasic" android:endColor="@color/orange" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Comment: Post the code of the layout.

Comment: try with BottomDialogFragment its work

Comment: @Amitpandey Sadly it didn't change anything

Comment: try adding your buttons to your layout

Comment: This should not be an `AlertDialog`, this is not what they are for. It should be a standalone screen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything on `onCreateDialog` because that is redundant. If you want your buttons to be part of your custom dialog. Add it through your Dialog fragment layout's XML.